# would the memory pointed by auto_ptr leak in case of never ending application?

Tags: c++

I need to run an application in an embedded system continuously. While implementing this application, i need to allocate lot of memory from Heap. If i use auto_ptr for those, when will that be freed ? As per my understanding, memory pointed by auto pointers would be freed upon exiting/terminating the application. It would not be freed automatically if application is not exited.
I can use reset() to free the memory like below.

```
auto_ptr<Test> testPtr(new Test);
testPtr.reset();
```

But then, the purpose of auto_ptr would be defeated if i do this. If i can do reset() at all places, i can do delete also at all the places.

Pls let me know whether memory pointed by auto_ptr would get freed even though application is not exited. If not, is there any otherway to freeup the memory, other than calling reset() ?

EDIT: In my case, auto_ptr is inside a class. That class object will be destroyed only upon exiting the application. As the application runs infinitely, class object will not be destroyed. Hence the issue. Pls consider this also.

EDIT: Answer: As i am using same auto_ptr for storing other objects, everytime i do assignment, auto_ptr assignment operator would take care of deleting previous object. So no leak even without call to reset.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the design of the class containing the auto_ptr instance. It would probably help if you explain the rules around the lifetime of the heap memory allocated against the auto_ptr instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory pointed by auto_ptr is released when auto_ptr instance is destroyed. For local auto_ptr instance, defined in a function, this happens when function exits. If auto_ptr instance is class member, it is destroyed when container class instance is destroyed. Global auto_ptr instance is destroyed when the program exits.

Comment: @Alex: In my case, auto_ptr is inside a class. That class object will be destroyed only upon exiting the application. As the application runs infinitely, class object will not be destroyed. Hence the issue.

Comment: @bj: What's the problem then? The class needs the resource until the program ends. Nothing to change.

Comment: @GMan: I want to point the auto_ptr to a new object each time some external event reaches my application. So i think, i need to do reset() and use the pointer again.

Comment: @bjskishore: It sounds like you want to use the `auto_ptr` assignment operator to achieve this. It will cause the previous pointer to be deleted and replaced with the new pointer.

Comment: @GMan, @Alex: I tested just now. Yes, it works that way. So no leak even without call to reset().

Answer (score 4):

`auto_ptr` gives you two things:

1. assignment transfers ownership
2. when an owning auto_ptr is destroyed, so is the data it owns

The application exiting only becomes relevant if/when you have global auto_ptr objects -- which rarely makes sense in the first place. A global auto_ptr referring to a dynamically allocated object can usually be replaced by by making the object itself global (but you generally want to avoid both).

For most normal uses of auto_ptr, exiting the application is irrelevant -- it's exiting the scope at which the auto_ptr is defined that matters. At that point, the object it owns gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The destructor for the auto_ptr class will invoke the delete operator on the pointer you specified when calling the constructor i.e. `new Test`. Invoking `auto_ptr::reset()` has the same effect.

The benefit is that you can use scope rules to automate the destruction of the object being pointed to by an `auto_ptr` instance.

In your example `testPtr` is being instantiated on the stack and will be destroyed once it is out of scope.

Consider this example:

```
void foo()
{
  //... do some work

  {
    auto_ptr<Test> testPtr(new Test);

    //... do something with testPtr

  } // *at this point testPtr is no longer in scope and the pointer held by this object
    // will be deleted

  //... do some additional work
}
```

Now obviously you could have not bothered using scope (i.e. {}) and just called `auto_ptr::reset()` where I marked * *but* this method has the benefit of working in the presence of exceptions and `return` statements and so on.